# how can i use a stream (java.util.stream) to handle an array in a nested for loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, functional-programming, java-stream

heres the problem im trying to solve for context: 'Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.'
i wanna know if its possible to use streams to solve this problem...
heres my code:

```
class Solution {
   
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int num1=0;
    int num2=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<nums.length; j++){
            if(i==j)
                j++;
            if(j>=nums.length)
                break;
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
                num1=i;
                num2=j;
            }//end of 3rd if
        }//end of 2nd loop
    }//end of 1st loop
       int[] sol={num1,num2} ;
        return sol;
    }//end method
}
```

Comment: If a number occurs twice in the array, can I use both occurrences?

Comment: The OP said you can't use the same element twice.  But I would think that the same value in two different locations in the array would be two different elements.  Of course, if the target is odd, it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several possibilities.
Here's the data and target.

```
int[] nums = { 1, 10, 12, 3, 19, 33 };
int target = 43;
```

The first is basically a nested `IntStream`.

- it streams ints for `i = 0 to nums.length-1`
- and for `k = i+1 to nums.length`
- filters on the first solution that sums to the target.
- then it saves the indices in an array and
- the array with the solution is returned. or -1, -1

Modified solution to filter first based on [Ole V.V's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) suggestion.

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, nums.length - 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, nums.length)
                .filter(k -> nums[i] + nums[k] == target)
                .mapToObj(k -> new int[] { i, k }))
        .flatMap(a -> a).findFirst()
        .orElse(new int[] { -1, -1 });
```

This solution is similar except it uses a different way to generate the indices.

- using division and the remainder operator generate all possible pairs of indices.
- add to the condition to skip test if the indices are the same ones.
- both cases, an array of -1,-1 is returned if the condition failed to be met.

```
int[] res = IntStream.range(0, nums.length * nums.length - 1).mapToObj(
        k -> new int[] { k / nums.length, k % nums.length })
        .filter(a -> a[0] != a[1]
                && nums[a[0]] + nums[a[1]] == target)
        .findFirst().orElse(new int[] { -1, -1 });

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

For the given array and target, both print

```
        
[1,5]
```

Keep in mind that these are no more efficient than a simple nested loop solution.  And if the supplied array consists of only positive numbers the loop solution can be made even more efficient by skipping individual values that already exceed the target.  And its important to break out of the loops as soon as a solution is found.

As far as your original solution goes, it can be improved as follows:

- start the outer loop from `i = 0 to nums.length-1`.
- the inner loop goes from  `j = i+1 to nums.length`. Thus i and j will never be the same values.
- as soon as the first solution is found, break out of the loops.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int result[] = { -1, -1 };
        outer: for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                    result[0] = i;
                    result[1] = j;
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea.  I hadn't considered that.  I will make the change.

Comment: Thanks for the response man i really apperciate it :)